# What are the important directories a c++ programmer should know about on a linux filesystem?

Tags: c++, include, filesystems, directory-structure

This is a question which has puzzled me for well over a year, but I've never bothered to try and answer it... until today...

I notice I have the SFML "libraries" installed under '/usr/local/include/SFML/'.

If I look inside that directory, I see that it contains mainly header files. So I am guessing an 'include' directory is supposed to contain header files rather than object files.

This raises the question. Where is 'cmath', or 'vector'?

Turns out, using find, they are placed in '/usr/include/c++/4.7/cmath' - basically '/usr/include/'

So what is the difference between a local include ('/usr/local/include') and the include directory ('/usr/include') ?

Also amongst the file-system I see many 'lib', 'lib32' and 'lib64' directors. My guess is that the compiled .cpp files, or object files, are in these directories. I am guessing that lib was the old directory to be used before 64 bit architectures entered the game. I am guessing that the modern accepted thing to do is put your 32 bit object files in lib32 and your 64 bit versions in lib64. Is that correct?

There is a '/usr/local/lib' directory.

But there is a '/usr/lib' directory also. Again, why have an additional "local" one?

Also, inside '/usr/' there is a 'lib', 'lib32' and 'lib64'. But, inside '/usr/' there is only one 'lib' directory. Why is this?

Comment: It's not `Linux`, it's `GNU Linux` – now go, and from now on do not sin anymore.

Comment: Is it really that critical?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure there is a concrete answer to this question, but I will try to give at least SOME guidance.

Typically `/usr/local` is used for "custom installations". That is, it's not part of the fundamental installation. Of course, that's a guideline, so you will still find some things that are installed in `/usr/lib`, when it should really be installed in `/usr/local/lib` (or `/usr/local/lib{32,64}` as appropriate).

And yes, `lib32` and `lib64` is for libraries that are size-dependent (although your program will work perfectly fine if you install 32-bit libraries in lib64 and 64-bit ones in lib32 - it's just harder to follow what is going on if you do that!).

Sometimes it's `lib` and `lib64` or `lib` and `lib32`. This varies depending on the distribution. And if there are `lib32` and `lib64`, the `lib` is often there to hold things that are "size-independant", such as configuration files that are stored in `/usr/lib`.

There are certainly OTHER directories that are useful to know about - your home directory, `/var/log/` for log files, `/var/run` for lock-files and `.pid` files and other "status" files for a specific application and there is a `/var/lib` directory too - which seems to contain some random selection of component-specific libraries. THe `/opt` (which is sort of another variant of `/usr/local/`) is sometimes used to store binaries, etc.

Edit:

Another category of directorys that may be useful to know about is the `/proc`, `/sys` and `/dev` directories.

`/proc` which is supported by the `procfs` filesystem driver in the kernel gives information about what the system is doing, e.g. `cat /proc/meminfo` will show statistics for the memory (and it's usage), `cat /proc/cpuinfo` will show what CPU's the machine has. `cat /proc/self/status` will show the current process's status. If you want to see what some other process does, `cat /proc/xx/status`, where `xx` is the process id (a number) will show what that other process is doing. Lots more available if you look inside there - some of it more useful than others.

The `/sys` is a similar structure to the `/proc`, but has things that are more "system" oriented, where `/proc` is more about processes, but there is some overlap.

The `/dev/` is the "root" for devices. `/dev/sda` would be one of your hard disks (but could have another name, depending on exactly what hard disks you have).

Comment: Hmm, okay thanks, so gcc libraries go in /usr/include because they are a standard thing, but sfml goes in the local include directory because sfml is a bit specialist or non-standard or not usually assumed to be available on a standard installation? Have I followed correctly?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Under SysV (and most commercial Unices), there won't be a `/usr/local/`.  Each "package" has its own directory under `/opt` (for optional), and _should_ be entirely contained there.  This has the great advantage that you can completely remove a package with `rm -fr /opt/package_name` (assuming adequate rights).  It also means that the compiler will only look for include files and link against libraries for packages that you specify (`-I/opt/package_name/include` and `-L/opt/package_name/lib`).

Answer (score 1):

You should read this (for the short version):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

and this (for all the boring details):

http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html